# Tricky general math question |Brain Challenger

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If anyone of you likes to take challenge questions, then I have it for you. It will help me to improve my brain memory as well.

**Q.** In a university with 300 students enrolled, 140 students are taking French, 120 are taking business, 130 are taking music, 30 are taking French and business, 40 are taking business and music, 50 are taking French and music, and 10 are taking French, business, and music. How many students:

**a.** are taking exactly two of those subjects?
**b.** are taking exactly one of those subjects?
**c.** are not taking any of the three subjects?

Best of luck!

Comment: Have you drawn a Venn diagram?  It is helpful in cases like this.

Comment: If you need help solving this I think this is just an application of the inclusion exclusion principle.

Comment: I second @RossMillikan's suggestion, with the added advice that the numbers in the question should be understood to cover not only the stated subject subsets, but also their supersets: For instance, $140$ students are taking French, *including those who are taking French in conjunction with other subjects*.  When one draws the Venn diagram, therefore, one cannot assign the "French only" partition $140$ students; they are assigned to all the areas covered by the French region, including those in overlap with other subjects.

Comment: With the way the counts are provided, it would be most fruitful to start at the "center" of the Venn diagram (the common intersection of all three subjects), and work your way outward.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I tried, but was not able to do further. Would you share your solution with us? Thanks!

Comment: @BrianTung, believe me, it is very hard to do. I tried.

Comment: @GhostRider: Draw three circles that mutually intersect, including a region where all three circles overlap.  Put $10$ (the number taking all three subjects) in that central region.  For the region where only French and business overlap, we know that there are $30$ taking French and business, but that includes the $10$ taking all three subjects, so the region where only French and business overlap gets $30-10 = 20$.  Continue with the other overlap portions, and repeat for the non-overlapping portions.

Comment: (I don't think it is hard to do, but I suspect you do not know how to get started.)

Comment: @GhostRider it is very easy to do this |-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a venn diagram to represent students subjects.[image]

First, calculate number of students are taking exactly two subjects.

FB+BM+FM $=(30-10)+(40-10)+(50-10)$

$20+30+40=90$

Thus, 90 students take exaxtly two of those subjects.

Now, calculate number of students are taking exactly one subject.

F=$140-(50+30)+10\;\;\implies 60+10=70$

B=$120-(30+40)+10\;\;\implies 50+10=60$

M=$130-(50+40)+10\;\;\implies 40+10=50$

F+B+M= $70+60+50=180$

Thus, 180 students take exactly one of those subject.

Calculate students are not taking any of those subjects.

$300-(90+180)\;\;\implies 300-280=20$

Hence, 20 students don't take any of three subjects.

Comment: OH! :( I did it wrong on the paper. I'm gone, but thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of what's called an inclusion-exclusion problem. Draw out a Venn diagram- it might help.

First, add up all the single-element sets: 140+120+130. There's a problem, though- we counted all the overlaps! But we can fix it. We just subtract all the two-element sets: -(30+40+50). Now the overlaps are corrected for, but we're missing the students who are taking all three classes. So we add them back in: +10. 140+120+130-30-40-50+10=280.

So that tells us there are 280 students taking French/Business/Music, or a combination of them. So for part c, we just subtract (300-280), to get the rest of the students.

For part a., you want to add up all the 2-student sets, and subtract the 3-student sets.

Part b, then, is just (part c)-(part b)-(10)- all the students taking at least one of those classes, minus the students taking two, minus the students taking 3.